# How to add items in the ListView in MVC project from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listview

I have seen many websites which show the way to do it is :

```
<ul>
@foreach (var customer in Model.Customer)
{
    <li>@customer</li>
} 
</ul>
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is to have a listview which adds data to it from an XML file.

I have done the same thing on a windows form whos code behind looks like:

```
            XElement xRoot = ManagerHelper.XMLManager().LoadOrderXML();

            var ordermodel = new OrderModel(xRoot).orders.List;
            lstbxClientNameNo.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var order in ordermodel)
            {
                lstbxClientNameNo.Items.Add(string.Format("{1} - {0}", 
                order.clientName, order.orderNumber));
            }
```

however could someone guide me to do the same/similar thing on an MVC project where I can pull the data from Model in View.

I have copied the model over to MVC from windows form and I wish to use the same data. The reason I'm building the same application on MVC is because I'm trying to learn MVC and how it works.

My model looks like:

```
public XElement LoadOrderXML()
        {
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

            xmldoc.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(MYFORLDERPATH));
            XElement xRoot = XElement.Parse(xmldoc.InnerXml);
            return xRoot;




  public class OrderModel
    {
        public Orders orders;

        public OrderModel(XElement xOrder)
        {
            orders = new Orders(xOrder);         
        }

        public class Order
        {
            public string orderNumber, clientName;
            public decimal totalOrderPrice;
            public Products products;

            public Order()
            {
            }

            public Order(XElement xOrder)
            {
                XElement xClientNumber = xOrder.Element("OrderNumber");
                XElement xClientName = xOrder.Element("ClientName");
                XElement xTotalOrderPrice = xOrder.Element("TotalOrderPrice");

                XElement xProduct = xOrder.Element("Products");

                if (xClientNumber == null) return;
                orderNumber = xClientNumber.Value;
                clientName = xClientName.Value;
                totalOrderPrice = decimal.Parse(xTotalOrderPrice.Value);
                products = new Products(xProduct);
            }

            public XElement ToXML()
            {
                var xOrder = new XElement("Order");

                var xClientNumber = new XElement("OrderNumber", orderNumber);
                var xClientName = new XElement("ClientName", clientName);
                var xTotalOrderPrice = new XElement("TotalOrderPrice", 
                                                    totalOrderPrice);
                var xProducts = new XElement("Products", products);
                xOrder.Add(xClientNumber);
                xOrder.Add(xClientName);
                xOrder.Add(xTotalOrderPrice);
                xOrder.Add(xProducts);

                return xOrder;
            }
        }

        public class Orders
        {
             private readonly List<Order> _list;
            public List<Order> List { get { return _list; } }

            public Orders(XElement xAddresses)
            {
                _list = new List<Order>();

                var xProductList = xAddresses.Descendants().ToList();

                foreach (XElement ele2 in xAddresses.Descendants("Order"))
                {
                    _list.Add(new Order(ele2));
                }
            }        
        }
```

Comment: Dude, what?! "_...accessing model from the view which is a bad practice._" The `Model` does not get magically rendered. The `View` is constructed around the `Model` which means that the `Model` must be "parsed", i.e. accessed.

Comment: I was looking at a wrong MVC diagram and I have edited the question

Comment: Do you already have a model defined? Do you wish to use the same data that is being used in the winforms app?

Comment: It would help if you could add the model and give additional info about what you need. Do you wish to display this `string.Format("{1} - {0}", order.clientName, order.orderNumber)` in your view?

Comment: Yes, that how I formatted the string and added into the listview in windows form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60175/discussion-between-yagnesh-cangi-and-andrei-v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments and code, I think that what you are looking for is this:

```
<ul>
@foreach (Order order in Model.orders.List)
{
    <li>@order.clientName - @order.orderNumber</li>
} 
</ul>
```

This assumes that your are sending an `OrderModel` object as the view model:

```
public ActionResult MyOrderAction()
{
    //get the XML
    XElement xmlData = ReadTheXmlData();

    //get the model
    OrderModel model = new OrderModel(xmlData);

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm very new to MVC and I don't know where to put MyOrderAction(). I assume it goes into controller.  What do i put in GetOrderModel()?

Comment: @YagneshCangi, yes, the action would go in the controller. I've changed it a bit, maybe it now sheds a little light on what to do next. Basically, you need to get the `XElement` from the XML files and then pass it to the `OrderModel` constructor. This method uses the existing logic of your model class.

Comment: I have added the codes and now it's giving me an error on @foreach - "'Mvc_Accounts.Models.OrderModel' does not contain a definition for 'Orders'".   Mvc-Accounts is what my project is called

Comment: @YagneshCangi, change this `public Orders orders;` to this `public Orders orders { get; set; }` and check my edit (in the view, write `order` with lowercase `o`).

Comment: Now I got a different error - "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Mvc_Accounts.Models.OrderModel.Orders' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @YagneshCangi, oops, you're right. I edited my answer (`@foreach (Order order in Model.orders.List)`). As a side note, your code is a a bit messy. You should consider refactoring it.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you soo much for your help. I will try to understand the codes and move forward with learning it.  Just few questions, which part of my code is messy so i get an idea of how to re-factor it and how did public ActionResult MyOrderAction() work. What if i want to use another XML? i would add ActionResult in controller but how will it be called if i create another one?

Comment: You're welcome. Please have a look at [serialization attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx) and try to look up some examples here on SO. They might make your code easier to read. Another suggestion would be to completely remove the XML parsing from your model and consider using a deserializer; it will automatically parse your XML and create your `OrderModel` object.

Comment: You can add parameters to the view (`MyOrderAction(string xmlName)`). The name could come from a value selected from a drop down list, for example. I would create a separate method that deserializes an XML, based on a file name you specify. You would then call this method from within your action method, passing the `xmlName` parameter. The method would return a new `OrderModel` object, populated with the data from the corresponding XML.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of it. I shall research on it and try to implement it on my work. Thank you for your help and your advice.